# Entity Framework LINQ Where condition is not working for string

Tags: string, entity-framework, where-clause

I have a database field `Contact varchar(50)` which contains data `"8801866968342"`.

In entity model I have `public string Contact { get; set; }`

```
  string contact="8801866968342";
 //following code is not working-
 var bp = db.BP.Where(s => s.Contact == contact).FirstOrDefault(); //bp==null here

//But this code is working.
 var bp = db.BP.Where(s => s.Id==2).FirstOrDefault();
```

How can I get working the string where condition?

Comment: What is "not working"? Error? No Result? You need to be more specific

Comment: Well, most likely the value in the database table is not exactly `"8801866968342"`, but contains some whitespace or non printable chars. You can load the record using the second approach (with the id of the record you think contains the `Contact` value in question) and check the length and/or content of the `Contact` property.

Comment: How about using `s.Contact.Contains("value")`?

Comment: @sallushan, Yes, its working. Thanks. Post it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `s.Contact.Contains("value")` which will be translated to `LIKE '%value%'` in T-SQL

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Equals()`:

```
var bp = db.BP.Where(s => s.Contact.Equals("8801866968342")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Or:

```
var bp = db.BP.Where(s => string.Equals(s.Contact, "8801866968342", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Also, check the collation used by your `Contact` field on the database. I suppose this is a numerical string.

Comment: I am wondering if Entity Framework will translate it to T-SQL correctly?

Comment: Yes it will, but in this case `==` is the same as `.Equals` and `Ordinal` will make no difference.